# Akka - router supervisorStrategy- how to send message to router on event

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-actor

Hi I want to implement a router strategy that on some event will send a message to the router, but I don't know how to get a reference to the router inside the strategy implementation.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 val router = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5, supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(){
      case _: ActorKilledException => Escalate
      case _: ActorInitializationException => Escalate
      case _ => self ! SomeMsg(); Restart
    }).props(Props(classOf[MyClass])))
```

Where self should be the router `ActorRef`, but self is not recognized in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I normally never create the case into the Router but outside

```
  val workerRouter: ActorRef = context.actorOf(
    Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

  val msgRouter: ActorRef = context.actorOf(
    Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfWorkers)), name = "msgRouter")
```

Then in my actor receiver function

```
def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case RunWorkersMsg =>
      workerRouter ! WorkMsg(i , numberOfElements)
    case ResultMsg(value) =>
      msgRouter ! WorkMsg()
  }
```

Here you can see my Akka project with an example https://github.com/politrons/Akka

Comment: I want to have a router because in my project there are x actors with the same code. now I need to send a message to the router when one of the routees is terminated(not broadcast, so only one of the existing routees will receive it). In your example if the actor dies then he won't be able to notify about its failure to exactly one of the x-1 existing living actors